# Pass a Class instance as an argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have a python script that in one of the lines calls a function that exists in another class, that exists in another script, i already imported the script and accessed to the function, but that function takes an argument which is an instance of the class itself.
the function is in script `model.py` and inside it a class called `Model` inside `Model`  is the function, the function inside **model.py**

```
  class Model(object):    
    def create_base(self,
      images,
      labels_one_hot,
      scope='AttentionOcr_v1',
      reuse=None):
```

so when i run the following code

```
import skimage.io as io
import numpy as np
import collections
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import common_flags
import model

from tensorflow.python.platform import flags

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
common_flags.define()

images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[635, 1219])
fn ='/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/6m.jpg'
images = [io.imread(fn, dtype='float')]
print(images)
images_actual_data = np.stack(images)
images_actual_data = 2.5*(images_actual_data - 0.5)  # normalize values



dataset = common_flags.create_dataset(split_name=FLAGS.split_name)
modelout = common_flags.create_model(dataset.num_char_classes,
                                    dataset.max_sequence_length,
                                    dataset.num_of_views, dataset.null_code)
endpoints = model.Model.create_base(images_placeholder, labels_one_hot=None)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_fn = model.create_init_fn_to_restore('/nsfs/tensor_models/models/research/attention_ocr/python/inception_v3.ckpt', '')
    init_fn(sess)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    predictions = sess.run(endpoints.predicted_chars, feed_dict={images_placeholder:images_actual_data.reshape(1,imHeight,imWidth,imChannel)})
    print predictions
```

i get the following error:

```
INFO 2017-11-20 15:08:46.000545: fsns.py: 130 Using FSNS dataset split_name=train dataset_dir=/nsfs/tensor_models/models/research/attention_ocr/python/datasets/data/fsns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_tf.py", line 31, in <module>
    endpoints = model.Model.create_base(images_placeholder, labels_one_hot=None)
TypeError: unbound method create_base() must be called with Model instance as first argument (got Tensor instance instead)
```

I'm new to python, so any idea that can help?
Thanks

Comment: Ordinary methods (not staticmethods or classmethods) are only meaningful if called on a particular instance of the class, not the class itself.  Perhaps you want `model.Model().create_base(...)`.  Or perhaps the `create_model()` on the previous line returned an instance of this Model, in which case you can use `modelout.create_base()`.  Or perhaps it should have been a staticmethod, if it truly doesn't need to refer to an instance at all.

Comment: So what's stopping you from instantiating an object of Model() and then calling create_base on it?

Comment: @ jasonharper  `modelout.create_base()` that actually worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it was advised in the comments, i used

```
endpoints = modelout.create_base(images_placeholder, labels_one_hot=None)
```

and it worked